# Moving the Facet wrap label below the x-axis affects the y-axis of the bottom plot when using Patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, patchwork

I stumbled across this yesterday and traced the issue to the relocation of the facet wrap label below the x-axis code. More specifically, to this segments of the code:

```
theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

If this is not done, patchwork has no problem combining plots and does not affect y-axis of the bottom plot. On their own, plots are fine, the problem emerges when doing the procedure as described. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

With the strip.placement = "outside":
[image: With the code]

Without the strip.placement = "outside":
[image: Without the code]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "theme(strip.placement = "outside")" to your plot at the panel (c).